# Case WHEN Date to String

Tags: string, date, case

I have a view that is pulling from a table that will be constantly updated can I use a case when that automatically takes the date column and provides me the string ( 'YYYY-MM') for every month ( all 12 and mutiple years as the table it draws from grows.

Currently I have this for every month

```
CASE WHEN t1.DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013 BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/14','MM/DD/YY') AND TO_DATE('01/31/14','MM/DD/YY') THEN '2014-01' ..... End ) as Year_Month
```

I would like the YEAR_MONTH to be When  DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013 is falls in month X then give me Year_MONTH as 'YYYY-MM' for year is the year represented in DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013

thanks kindly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Format such as this:

```
 CASE WHEN t1.DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013 BETWEEN TO_DATE('01/01/14','MM/DD/YY') AND TO_DATE('01/31/14','MM/DD/YY') THEN Format(t1.DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013,"yyyy-mm") ..... End ) as Year_Month
```

Comment: The one issue is that I can't limit the code to a specific year. Month is fine but years are continous

Comment: Not sure what you mean doesn't the t1.DATE_OF_SERVICE_3013 change?

Comment: @Tinkinc can you provide some more info. How does the view pull th information from the table and where is this result ("YYYY-MM") that you are after get stored?

Comment: Sorry top get back to you so late, So the Date of service can range from 2014 to 201X, i want to have a string 'YYYY-MM'that adds a column based on the date of service parameter of months 1 through 12 and Year X which then would give the record a string YYYY-MM based on the actual date parameters of "date of service"

Comment: So again I understand that part but how and where do you want this information in a spreadsheet in a table in a form where is the information coming from and where is it going? If I know that I think I can find a solution for you.

Comment: All of this is going to add another column to a table in oracle. So Date of Service wont leave it will just be Date of Service, Record, and YEAR_MONTH. In theory.    Which will make anytime a record is added regardless of a finite year it will populate the YEAR_MONTH with yyyy-mm off of the date of service( which is in date format)

Comment: So this could work, except I only want YYYY-MM CONVERT(varchar(23), [MyDateTimecolumn], 121)

Comment: All you need to do if use Format it will return the Date the way that you want it but it will create multiple if that is ok then it should work.

Comment: All you really need is when a record is added have a query run that calculates the new field as =Format([date of service], YYYY-MM)

Comment: I dont think that works with ORACLE, I used to_CHAR which seems to work fine thus far.  I was getting invalid Identifier with FORMAT

Comment: can you convert it to a date after format like =cdate(Format([date of service], YYYY-MM)). Sorry I know VBA but not oracle so I cannot really help to much with that.

Comment: It seems to me that you could convert first TO_CHAR and then chop off the Day part and then convert it back TO_DATE with oracle. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements004.htm